# How to use zenject outside and inside Unity, but with different DiContainers?

Tags: zenject

I am developing a platform for a videogame, it is pure c # code and I want to use Zenject for dependency injection. The idea is that this platform can initialize its dependency injection regardless of where it is being used. I have this class on the platform:

```
public static class DIManager
    {
        private static DiContainer _container;

        public static DiContainer Container {get => _container; set => _container = value; }

        public static void Initialize ()
        {
            _container = new DiContainer ();
            InstallBindings ();
        }

        private static void InstallBindings ()
        {
            _container.Install <AppInstaller> ();
        }

    }
```

which creates and initializes the container that is used in the platform, but to use it outside the platform I always have to call:

```
_foo = DIManager.Container.TryResolve <Foo> ();
```

Is this a correct way to implement the idea I want? Is this way of obtaining a platform class optimal (in terms of performance)? Any ideas or suggestions you have will be appreciated, greetings.